# RMarkdown tikz engine in ioslides presentation

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, ioslides

Whereas the following minimal example works with `output: html_document` it doesn't with `output: ioslides_presentation`.
Any ideas why?

````
 ---
 title: "Tikz test"
 output: ioslides_presentation
 ---

 ## Tikz Example

 ```{r,engine='tikz', fig.ext='svg'}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 ```
````